# Calling a Powershell script from a batch file and terminate upon failure

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to call a Powershell script inside a batch file

For example.

test.ps1

```
function func1(){
#Do something
}

function func2(){
#Do something
}

func1()
func2()
```

Batch script

```
:: Do something

PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""test.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"

:: Exit execution if powershell execution failed.
```

How can I terminate the execution of batch file if the powershell execution encounters any problem.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and ditch the batch part entirely. Anyway, use exit <value> to return a value to %errorlevel%

Comment: You use CMD to start a Powershell to start another Powershell ... really? ... why?

Comment: @Olaf I'm quite new to powershell and batch. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: OK, so just use the inner most command you have in your code as command line to start the Powershell script ... that's all you need.

Comment: @Olaf can I run the Powershell as admin using only the inner command?

Comment: @Sameera Would it hurt a lot you when you just tried?  ;-) :-D ... you may run `Powershell /?` in your CMD to learn about the options you have.

Comment: :D :D It didn’t work actually. Just wanted to ask the best way of doing it.

Comment: `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "test.ps1" -Verb RunAs`